# Scala - How to handle the Non string values ( Date, Double, Boolean) while building Json by looping with Map and Object Array

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, scala

Scala - How to handle the Non string values ( Date, Double, Boolean)in building Json by looping with Map and Object Array

in the below example I am always ending up having non string values as string.
in Values Array

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import java.time.Instant
import scala.util.Random

val Name:Array[String] = Array("Tester1","Tester2","Tester3")
val Typeids:Array[String] = Array("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000302","00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000003272","00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000006272")
val values:Array[Any] = Array(1264.3,java.time.LocalDate.now,"For Testing")

  val i = 0
  val data1 = (i to 2)
    .map { r =>
      Json.toJson(Map(
        "Name" -> Json.toJson(s"${Name(r%Name.length)}"),
        "typeId" -> Json.toJson(s"${Random.shuffle(Typeids.toList).head}"),
        "value" -> Json.toJson(s"${values(r%values.length)}")))    }


val data2 = Json.toJson(data1)
println(data2)
```

**Result :**

[{"Name":"Tester1","typeId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000006272","value":**"1264.3"**},{"Name":"Tester2","typeId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000302","value":**"2022-10-19"**},
{"Name":"Tester3","typeId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000006272","value":"For Testing"}]

**Expected result :**

[{"Name":"Tester1","typeId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000006272","value":**1264.3**},{"Name":"Tester2","typeId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000302","value":**2022-10-19**},{"Name":"Tester3","typeId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000006272","value":"For Testing"}]

Please suggest a solution with an example, any method to achieve the expected result will be helpful to handle non-string

Comment: The `double` might be possible, but the date will not be possible -- 2022-10-19 isn't a valid JSON value.  That said, my bet is that there's some inference being done on the fact that you have an `Array[Any]`, not an array of numbers.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks for responding.
I can convert the date to unixtime and try as double.
I guess the issue is at "value" -> Json.toJson(s"${values(r%values.length)}")
taking all data types as string.

Comment: > I guess the issue is at "value" -> Json.toJson(s"${values(r%values.length)}") taking all data types as string. --- Yes, exactly. Don't convert things to string unless you want to

Comment: @Dima Thanks for responding.
I dont want to convert it, but how to handle
if the 
val values:Array[Any] = Array(1264.3,java.time.LocalDate.now,"For Testing")
and should be called in loop "value" -> Json.toJson(values(r%values.length))
and here I get error that Json.toJson.
Also the array has string too.

Comment: Either check the type of element at run time and handle it accordingly, or (much better!) do not put elements of different types into the same array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a helper method like,

```
def toJson(a: Any): JsValue = a match {
  case d: Double => Json.toJson(d)
  case i: Instant => Json.toJson(i.toEpochMilli)
  case o => Json.toJson(s"$o")
}
```

and use it as `"value" -> toJson(values(r % values.length))`

Comment: I am getting error asking me to implicit Values and handle with Write or Format Json
If you have any examples please suggest

Comment: Something like: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/KJte6WU4SJi1Kv22YkVebA

Comment: thank you very much.
you are a saviour